# Should/can some sort of disclaimer be added to the profile section?

Tags: discussion, legal-advice, disclaimer

I've noticed a lot of questions and answers contain statements like "I am not a lawyer and I'm not giving legal advice" etc. Would it be simpler and safer to include this in the user profile description? For example adding something like this to the "about me" part

> All questions, answers, comments and any other material added to the
>   law.stackexchange.com site, or any other stack exchange site, from
>   this account:
>   1.    Should not be construed as asking or giving legal advice; and
>   2.    Should not be admissible as any form of evidence into any court of law, arbitration, mediation or the like; and
>   3.    Does not necessarily represent a real life situation, and may be partially or wholly hypothetical

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of things here:

1. It's not clear whether a disclaimer of this sort would be enforceable, or how enforceable it would be, given that you need to navigate to the user's profile (which, if you intended to rely on it, you would likely need to show that your prospective defendant had done).
2. There's already a disclaimer on pretty much every page of the main site as we could get it:
   [image: Disclaimer: this screenshot of the disclaimer may be outdated due to site changes.]

On balance, I don't necessarily think that this would improve things - it would merely give people a false sense of security, and in my view, if you hid something like this in the user profile, it would simply mean that fewer users would see it, thus limiting its effect.